# http doesn't forward to https on Google Chrome

Tags: redirect, iis, https, iis-10

I have a website: https://www.example.com running on IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016.  I have URL forwarding set up so that if somebody goes to the non-www URL, it redirects to the www.  If they go to http it redirects to https.  In the past this has worked just fine.

Today I get a call that somebody can't get on to the site.  Turns out that Google Chrome doesn't redirect http to https -- it comes back with a 403.  Every other browser I've tried works fine (including the new MS Edge, which is Chromium-based). Going to https://example.com does successfully redirect to the www.

Here's the redirect, which has worked just fine until (not sure when) recently.  I have tried these in either order.

```xml
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Force www." enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^pwaportal\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.pwaportal.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Force SSL (https)" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    ...
</rules>
```

Note: If somebody has successfully pulled up the page in the past, it works fine. Chrome I suppose is caching the final URL, or the fact that it should use https for that domain.

UPDATE: The Plot Thickens: I tried it on Safari. Safari downloaded a 0-byte file called "example.com"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Enable FRT and read it.

Comment: Tried that. Got a log file that’s a mile long and incomprehensible to me

Comment: Open it in a web browser and learn how to interpret it. In general it is one of the easiest log approach to analyze if you consider other stuffs on Windows such as ETW.

Comment: Web browser gives me Wall O' Text (FF, IE) or nothing at all (Chrome).  I'm better off trying to read it in Notepad

Comment: You'd better review your log folder structure and browser settings, as others simply see well rendered elements in their browsers as documented, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#analyzing-failed-request-tracing-log-file

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with the Google Chrome instead of URL rules. Please try below and test it again. First, please allow Http protocol, add the domain name. chrome://net-internals/#hsts By default, the http URL will be replaced with Https URL. Second, Delete all local copy/cache. Third.  Always test the result in the incognito windows. Besides, your testing URL should meet the URL conditions.